# Pass a Make variable to Bashscript that is invoked from inside Make

Tags: bash, shell-script, make, gnu

In a pattern rule I would like to export `make` variable like `$(TargetLocation)`, `$@`.

I tried the following but It didn't get exported. The bash script is executable.

```
export $(TargetLocation); \
export $@; \
./EditHtml.sh;
```

I also tried this (I have used `${VarA}` instead of `${TargetLocation}` inside bash script), but it didn't get exported:

```
./EditHtml.sh VarA=$(TargetLocation); \
```

I would like to use these variables in the Bash script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the variable name, not the value.

You can either export the name for all sub processes with the GNU Make `export` statement

```
export TargetLocation
```

If you want the value just for one rule, then your statement must be regular shell syntax

```
    export TargetLocation="$(TargetLocation)"; \
    ./EditHtml.sh
```

In this case, depending on the content of the variable, quotes may be necessary, and it would still be vulnerable if there may be arbitrary values for the variable. On the other hand, if make runs with the privileges of the invoking user, there is no additional danger.

Comment: Thanks. This `export TargetLocation` didn't work but this `export TargetLocation="$(TargetLocation)"; \ ./EditHtml.sh` did work

Comment: Nicer looking: `TargetLocation="$(TargetLocation)" ./EditHtml.sh` (no need to `export` here).

Comment: @Kusalananda While using your answer. Do we need to make `EditHtml.sh` executable? Also, is this a general shellscript syntax: I mean Can I pass variable to bashscript from terminal (outside make) as you did? Hoping that you could explain these things in an answer.

Comment: @Nikhil I won't write an answer for this. Using `variable=value utility` is standard shell syntax and will set `variable` to `value` in the environment of `utility`. If your script is not executable, you would need to use an explicit interpreter (`bash` or `sh` or whatever shell the script is written for) so that you have `variable=value sh script`.